# Does C++11 require this lambda to be declared mutable?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, visual-studio-2013, language-lawyer

Consider this C++11 code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename F>
void test(F &&f) {
    auto foo = [f]() {
        f();
    };
    foo();
}

int main() {
    test(std::bind(std::puts, "hello"));
    return 0;
}
```

GCC and Clang accept this as valid C++11 code, but Visual Studio 2013 requires the lambda to be declared mutable (`auto foo = [f]() mutable { ... }`). Otherwise I get this error:

> error C3848: expression having type '`const std::_Bind<true,int,int (__cdecl *const )(const char *),const char (&)[6]>`' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call '`int std::_Bind<true,int,int (__cdecl *const )(const char *),const char (&)[6]>::operator ()<>(void)`'

Is Visual Studio right to reject this code without mutable, or is it valid C++11?

(Curiously Clang rejects the code if you change `std::bind(std::puts, "hello")` to `std::bind(std::exit, 0)` apparently because it considers `noreturn` to make the function type different; I'm quite sure this is a bug.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This isn't really about lambdas.

```
#include <functional>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
  const auto x = std::bind(std::puts, "hello");
  x();
}
```

This is accepted by GCC, but rejected by MSVC.

The standard is unclear on whether this is valid, IMO. The return value `g` of `std::bind` has an unspecified return type for which `g(...)` is valid and defined in terms of the cv-qualifiers of `g`, but the standard doesn't actually say that any `operator()` must be callable for `const`-qualified objects or references. It strongly implies that this is intended to be valid, because otherwise the reference to `g`'s cv-qualifiers seems useless, but it doesn't actually say it is valid.

Because of that, I think MSVC's behaviour is not what the standard's authors intended, but it may nonetheless conform to what the standard requires.

Comment: No, it doesn't conform to the standard. "The effect of `g(u1, u2, ...,
 uM)` shall be `INVOKE (fd, v1, v2, ..., vN, result_of<FD cv (V1, V2, ..., VN)>::type)`" means that the result of `bind` must be callable if the bound function object is. The function pointer is callable whether or not it's `const`, so the `bind` thing must also be.

Comment: @MikeSeymour `g` is the return value of `std::bind`, and only `g(...)`'s behaviour is specified. Where does the standard require supporting calls through a `const`-qualified reference to that return value?

Comment: In the quote I gave above (20.8.9.1.2/3), plus the following clause "where `cv` represents the cv-qualifiers of `g`". Calling `g` has the same effect as invoking `fd` (the bound function object) with the cv-qualifiers of `g` applied to `fd`; so a call to a `const`-qualified copy/reference of `g` must be valid if an invocation of `const FD` is. Here, `FD` is a function pointer type, which is callable whether or not it's `const`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour `g` is the forwarding wrapper returned by `bind`, and *only* `g` is required to be callable. When you add cv-qualifiers, you've no longer got `g`. Again, it's almost certainly *intended* to be valid, but the standard doesn't actually say so.

Comment: OK, I suppose an ultra-pedantic reading could be that the behaviour of copies or references isn't properly specified. I should know better than to get involved with language-lawyer discussions.

Answer (score 10):

This looks like a bug in the Visual Studio implementation of `bind`, returning a type with only a non-const function call operator. It should return a type that forwards all function calls to the bound function object, regardless of its own cv-qualifications.

To summarise the rather opaque language of C++11 20.8.9.1.2, function calls on the result of `bind` should be forwarded to the bound function object, and so should be allowed if calls on that object would be allowed. So it would be an error if the bound function object weren't callable if `const`; but here, being a function pointer, it is callable regardless of cv-qualifications.